# assign name base on the value in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, there's a column as color code from 1-5

```
| color code |
| 1          |
| 3          |
| 3          |
| 5          |
| 2          |
```

each color code means
1=Yellow, 2=White, 3=Black, 4=Blue, 5=Brown

How do I create a new column assign each color code a color name like below?

```
| color code |color name|
| 1          | Yellow   |
| 3          | Black    |
| 3          | White    |
| 5          | Brown    |
| 2          | White    |
```

Comment: Now that your question has been edited and I can see the expected output I am not entirely sure what you are asking. Does 3 correspond to both Black and White? And 2 is also White? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Define a [factor](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/factor) variable. From [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html):

> In R, factors are used to work with categorical variables, variables that have a fixed and known set of possible values. They are also useful when you want to display character vectors in a non-alphabetical order.

It is worth reading that chapter - and really the entire book - as factors are a fundamental building block of data frames in R.

In this particular case, you need to set the `labels` of the factor to your color names, and the `levels` to your numeric values:

```r
dat  <- data.frame(
    color_code = c(1,3,3,5,2,4)
)

color_codes = c(
    `1` = "Yellow", `2` ="White", `3` = "Black", `4` = "Blue", `5` = "Brown"
)

dat$color_name  <- factor(
    dat$color_code,
    levels = as.integer(names(color_codes)),
    labels = color_codes
)

dat

#   color_code color_name
# 1          1     Yellow
# 2          3      Black
# 3          3      Black
# 4          5      Brown
# 5          2      White
# 6          4       Blue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `factor`

```
dat$color_name <- factor(dat$color_code, 
                     levels = 1:5,
                     labels=c("Yellow", "White", "Black", "Blue", "Brown"))
dat
  color_code color_name
1          1     Yellow
2          3      Black
3          3      Black
4          5      Brown
5          2      White
6          4       Blue
```

I used @SamR data.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve your problem:

```
dat$color_name = c("Yellow", "White", "Black", "Blue", "Brown")[dat$color_code]
```

Another solution

```
colors = c(`1`="Yellow", `2`="White", `3`="Black", `4`="Blue", `5`="Brown")

dat$color_name = unname(colors[as.character(dat$color_code)])
```